# Basic linear system with Gauss

Tags: matrices

I'm studying linear systems and I'm looking for the method to solve this exercize :

Find the values of $(a,b,c,d) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ \text{such as the linear system with unknow} \ x_1 \ x_2 \ \text{has solutions} :$

$x_1+x_2=a \\
3x_1-x_2=b \\
-x_1+2x_2=c \\
-2x_1+x_2=d \\ $

I usually have linear systeps with a,b,c,d given reals and have to find the values of x so I've just to do Gauss method to solve it, however with x unknown I don't see how to find a,b,c,d.
Thank you

Comment: Apply Gaussian elimination as far as you can. You will see some LHS turn to $0$, and you will conclude about the allowed values of the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

here is what happens when you do gauss reduction

$\pmatrix{1&1&|&a\\3&-1&|&b\\-1&2&|&c\\-2&1&|&d}\to \pmatrix{1&1&|&a\\0&-4&|&-3a+b\\0&3&|&a+c\\0&3&|&a+d}\to
\pmatrix{1&1&|&a\\0&-12&|&-9a+3b\\0&12&|&4a+4c\\0&12&|&4a+4d}\to
\pmatrix{1&1&|&a\\0&-12&|&-9a+3b\\0&0&|&-5a+3b+4c\\0&0&|&-5a+3b+4d}$

from the last two rows you can see that you need the compatibility conditions $$ -5a+3b+4c= 0,-5a+3b+4d =0$$ for the system of equations to be consistent, i.e. for the system to have any solutions.